# .htacess 301 Redirect not working in Firefox

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am using the code below, which works fine in Chrome, but it is not working in Firefox. I have cleared cache and reloaded Firefox many times. It seems if I just type oursite.com it will redirect to https, but once I type www.oursite.com, it does not redirect and on subsequent oursite.com entries, it doesn't redirect while that same window is open.
The goal is to redirect all traffic, no matter what the url typed, to the https.....www.... version of the site.

```
 RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oursite\.com [nc]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.oursite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Remove `^` from `^oursite\.com`, or remove the condition entirely.

Comment: That didn't work...it threw a too many redirect errors in both browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oursite\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.oursite\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/www\.oursite\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```